# Find Rows with no leaf - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, substring

I have data in below format in a table .

| NAME | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| A | ABC |
| A | ABC:A |
| C | XYZ:C |
| E | XYZ:C:D |
| F | XYZ:C:D |

I am trying to get the output of only records which are leaf nodes, so basically I am looking to get output like

| NAME | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| A | ABC:A |
| E | XYZ:C:D |
| F | XYZ:C:D |

I tried doing nested substring on the PATH column but it giving me all rows.

My Trail :--

```
select * from TEST
   where 
      PATH NOT IN 
       ( select DISTINCT(substr(PATH, instr(PATH, ':', 1) + 1))from TEST)
```

The substr is not taking complete path and not able to find the last parent path.

Regards.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Added my query and there are no error . Just that output is not as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the paths, you can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery using `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM test t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM test t2
                                WHERE t2.path <> t1.path
                                      AND t2.path LIKE t1.path || ':%');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=38b87aced60e2ae8e42f7c22c3da6d28)